# how to do a retrieve user posts from this database design?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Using mysql

DB design:

```
Users:
- userId
- userName

Posts:
- postId
- text

UserPosts (many-many):
- userId (FK)
- postId (FK)
```

I want to retrieve all the posts made by all the users. This is what I need:

```
- userName
- text
```

I'm not quite sure how to write this query. How do I do this 3 way join ??

Comment: So, many users can write one post? What kind of system is this? Didn't you overengineer?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev One user can write many posts. The same post can be reposted by some other user. Think twitter.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev - Could be some sort of wiki system for all we know.

Comment: Join `Users` and `Posts` through `UserPosts`, select the requisite columns from each. Is this an extremely-basic SQL question (nothing wrong with that), or is there some twist that hasn't been revealed yet?

Comment: @JonH: Well, I was just finding it strange, that he came up with many-to-many schema and is not able to query it. It's basic stuff in any SQL book.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev - *shrug* maybe he is learning the syntax now, never too late to learn even if it is beginners at least he was able to describe the issue with enough information.  To me that's a good starting point.

Comment: @JonH: agreed, good questions are rare to find here :-)

Comment: @everyone: Thanks! I've not done sql for a long time now, hence the noob question. I was doing the same thing as you all mentioned, just that my syntax was way off, but now it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      u.userName, 
      p.Text
FROM 
      UserPosts up 
INNER JOIN
      Users u 
ON  
      u.userID = up.userID
INNER JOIN 
      Posts p ON p.postID = up.postID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Posts.text,
       Users.userName
FROM UserPosts
INNER JOIN Users on UserPosts.userId = Users.userId
INNER JOIN Posts on UserPosts.postId = Posts.postId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userName, text FROM Users,Posts,UserPosts 
WHERE 
UserPosts.userID = Users.userId AND UserPosts.postID = Posts.postID
```

Comment: Horizontal scrolling is evil :-)

Comment: I definitively will not -1 you, since performance wise they are the same using the `INNER JOIN` syntax as opposed to your solution.  From a readability perspective I prefer explicitly stating the JOIN type.